# Make control+d delete the current line in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyterlab

For many years, `control`+`d` has meant "delete the current line", in Jupyter Lab and in other applications.
Today, however, `control`+`d` suddenly changed to mean "highlight current word". I do not know why it changed, and I would like it to change back.

I'm running Ubuntu, with Jupyter lab `4.0.2` and Python `3.10.6`. I'm accessing the server using `Mozilla Firefox 113.0`, if that matters (although happy to change browsers).

I got as far as `settings` → `settings editor` → `Keyboard Shortcuts` → `JSON Settings Editor`, which lets me view what appears to be the configuration file for keyboard shortcuts.

There is a comment containing the heading *"List of commands followed by keyboard shortcuts"*; Unfortunately, when I pour through this list, there isn't any hint of a "delete line" verb that I could bind to a shortcut.

Does anyone know how to get the old behavior of `control`+`d` back in Jupyter Lab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug caused by upgrading `jupyterlab` from version `3.6.4` to versions `4.0.0` and higher. Presently, this remains unresolved. There is no documented user-friendly way to restore the "delete line" shortcut.

Instead, downgrade your jypyterlab installation using `pip3 install --user jupyterlab==3.6.4` to recover the delete-line shortcut.